# Prove that $ ^{\mathbb{N}}\mathcal P \left({\mathbb{N}}\right) \sim \mathcal P \left({\mathbb{N}}\right) $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The set of all functions from $ A $ to $ B $ is denoted $ ^{A}B $.  Prove that $ ^{\mathbb{N}}\mathcal P \left({\mathbb{N}}\right) \sim \mathcal P \left({\mathbb{N}}\right) $.

Previous question proved that for any set $ A $, $ ^{A}\{yes,no\}\sim \mathcal P \left({A}\right) $.  The symbol $ \sim $ means equinumerous to.  $\mathbb{N}$ does not include $0$ here.  $\mathcal P$ is power set operation.  I know we have to create a bijection between $ ^{\mathbb{N}}\mathcal P \left({\mathbb{N}}\right) \sim \mathcal P \left({\mathbb{N}}\right) $.  I believe I might be close to a solution, but am looking for some suggestions first.

Comment: It is easier to first show that $^{\mathbb{N}}\mathcal P \left({\mathbb{N}}\right)\sim \mathcal P(\mathbb N\times\mathbb N)$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Can you give an outline of this approach as an answer please?

Answer (score 1):

$\lvert \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})^\mathbb{N} \rvert = \lvert \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) \rvert ^ {\lvert \mathbb{N} \rvert} = (2 ^ {\lvert \mathbb{N} \rvert})^{\aleph_0} = (2 ^ {\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0^2} = 2^{\aleph_0} = 2^{\lvert \mathbb{N} \rvert} = \lvert \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) \rvert$. Since $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})^\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ have the same cardinality, there is a bijection between them.

An explicit bijection $f : \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})^\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is

$$ f(x) = \{ \pi(n, m) \mid n \in \mathbb{N}, m \in x(n) \} $$

where $\pi : \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is the [Cantor pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function). The inverse is

$$ f^{-1}(y)(n) = \{ m \mid (n, m) \in \{ \pi^{-1}(p) \mid p \in y \} \} $$

Comment: Is $\lvert \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})^\mathbb{N} \rvert$  suppose to be the same as $^{\mathbb{N}}\mathcal P \left({\mathbb{N}}\right) $  If so how do we get: $\lvert \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})^\mathbb{N} \rvert = \lvert \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) \rvert ^ {\lvert \mathbb{N} \rvert}$

Comment: My $B^A $ is the same as your $^A B $. Not sure why you use the latter notation when the former is standard.

Comment: $\lvert B^A \rvert = \lvert B \rvert ^ {\lvert A \rvert }$ is a general property of cardinality.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  One more thing $\lvert B^A \rvert = \lvert B \rvert ^ {\lvert A \rvert } $  I have a proof for this for finite sets using induction.  But I don't have one for infinite sets.  Can you reference  a proof for it?  Thanks.

Comment: I don't have a general proof handy, but wouldn't the bijection I gave in my answer suffice for your example?

Comment: Your example is fine,  I'm still looking for the more general proof of $ \lvert B^A \rvert = \lvert B \rvert ^ {\lvert A \rvert }$.  Also I posted an answer using your function above.  Can you check it?

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from Carlos' function above.

Suppose $ y\neq x $.  Then for some $ n\in\mathbb{N} $ we have $ x(n) \neq y(n) $.  Then there exists $ m\in\mathbb{N} $ for which $ m\in x(n) $ and $ m\notin y(n) $.  Since $ m\in x(n) $ it follows that $ \pi(n,m)\in f(x) $ by definition of $ f$.  Also since $ m\notin y(n) $ it follows that $ \pi(n,m)\notin f(x) $.  Since $ \pi $ is injective there exists no other integers $ p $ and $ q $ such that $\pi(n,m)=\pi(p,q)$ .  Therefore, $f(x)\neq f(y)$.

Suppose $ X\in \mathbb{N} $ and $ X $ is arbitary. Let $ z\in X $ where $ z $ is arbitary.  Since $\pi$ is surjective there exists $ n,m $ such that $ \pi(n,m)=z $.  Let $ x(n)=\{m\ |\ \pi(n,m)=z\} $.  Now by definition of $ f $ we have $ f(x)=X $ as required.